# comma separated field and comma separated search data

Tags: postgresql

I can do this:

```
SELECT id, name, data FROM public.app 
WHERE data=ANY(string_to_array('25,2,3,15', ',')::character varying[])
```

this is work correctly. But data field varchar and it will hold data which comma separated. In summary,

searching data= 25,2,3,15
db.field data=3,0,2,15,3,15 etc. both side include comma separated data.

I try this:

```
SELECT id, name, data FROM public.app 
WHERE string_to_array(data,',')=ANY(string_to_array('25,2,3,15', ',')::character varying[])
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently comparing two arrays using `ANY` when that is incorrect.

If you want to see if the two arrays are identical in their contents, you can simply remove `ANY`:

```
string_to_array(data,',') = (string_to_array('25,2,3,15', ',')::character varying[])
```

If you want to see if there is overlap between the two arrays, you use `&&`:

```
string_to_array(data,',') && (string_to_array('25,2,3,15', ',')::character varying[])
```

Additional operators are available here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html